# Azure service bus intermittent "40400: Endpoint not found"

Tags: azure, servicebus

I'm having odd errors with Azure Service Bus. For long running apps, using the batch api so that I can read a batch of messages at once (and throttle back when I have no messages available etc.), I will eventually start to get "40400: Endpoint not found" errors. These are only transient in that it doesn't stop everything but, once they occur they are intermittently persistent.

I also regularly get Message Lock lost exceptions, with 60 second timeouts, for updating batches of messages (max. 100 at a time). This really shouldn't be happening as it's running under "test" conditions where the messages are read, nothing happens to them, and then I complete them (i.e. there is no "programming logic" that takes any time at all to cause the timeout).

I really don't know how to work out why these occur and what I can do to prevent them.

Obviously I have all the re-try logic so that it doesn't bring down my app but, eventually, my app will process messages so slowly that in effect it's doing nothing at all.

My suspicion is that its because my queue (a "global worldwide queue") resides in North Europe but my app resides in East US, so the latency is causing an issue. If this is the case then I'm really stumped as it's an Azure data center communicating with another Azure data center (so should be fast) and then secondly, how on earth should you architect global queues for distributed access if the performance is so bad? AFAIK Service Bus doesn't support single endpoint globally distributed queues...

Comment: Do your error messages include a TrackingId and service Timestamp?

Comment: Yes they did. Looking into this further, I think the queue was corrupt somehow (i'd deleted it and re-created it to clear 1M+ records). The Azure Service Bus Explorer tool I also use had problems reading the dead letter queue. I've now nuked the queue, left it a few hours and re-created it. I'll try the same volume test again next week

Comment: Also, all my problems appear to be related to latency. I was getting terrible throughput, with sometimes the queue seemingly to not process anything at all for 5-6 secs. When I switched to run the consumer in the UK, against a North Europe queue as opposed to an East US consumer against the queue, it performed blisteringly quick in comparison. Therefore I'm stumped as to how to handle global queue distribution - on my experience so far Service Bus is actually unusable for this scenario